# onDestroy method is invoked when my Activity is pushed to background

Tags: android, cordova, android-lifecycle

I am running into issue where OnDestroy method is invoked on SecondActivity when I try to bring my Main Activity to foreground. onDestroy method is NOT invoked in demo application, however onDestroy method gets invoked in my main project whenever I bring MainActivity to foreground(module1).. 
Use case:

1) Launch app
2) MainActivity is running in Foreground
3) Navigate to SecondActivity
4) Tap on back button -> Brings the MainActivity to foreground

Note: I don't want OnDestroy to be called when I bring MainActivity to foreground.
Observation:  I manually thrown the Exception onDestroy to find the Stacktrace in my main project and please find the exception below. Once I bring the MainActivity to foreground, then SecondActivity gets killed as soon as I perform any actions on MainActivity. In demo app and my project, I am using Cordova frameworks to navigate between activity..

```
Exception: 
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at com.test.abc.mashup.SecondActivity.onDestroy(SecondActivity.java:240)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7102)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1170)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5084)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:221)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1853)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
01-11 18:16:43.806 29045-29045/c W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
01-11 18:16:44.931 29045-29045/c D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
01-11 18:16:44.966 29045-29045/c I/Choreogr
```

Module1: Manifest.xml

```
 <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/activity_name"  android:noHistory="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Module1: Main Activity

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //do something based on the intent's action
                Intent  nativeIntent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                context.startActivity(nativeIntent);

            }
        };
```

Module2: Manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
    </activity>
```

Module2: Second Activity

```
// onBackPressed event
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.myapp.mycustomaction");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Did you check "Do not keep activities" in the developer mode settings?

Comment: It's turned OFF...

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the "launchMode" parameter:

> A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task.

Launching any other activity within the same process will cause the following behavior:

> If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task — as if FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK was in the intent.

See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode - It includes a table showing what the different launchmodes do.

Comment: I do not understand, how come it works in my demo application with the same snippet, but it doesn't work in my Project..

Comment: You will need to specify how the demo application differs from your main project. Otherwise we can only guess why the activity ends

Comment: I don't see any difference between demo application and main project. I see the Manifest and other code seems to be the same. I am not sure what makes the difference at this point.

Comment: I have updated my observations regarding my demo aoplication and my Project